# Error TS2769 with protect middleware in express.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I try to protect routes on Express server.So I simplified my middleware to this yet I still catch an error:

> src/routes/userRoutes.ts:10:19 - error TS2769: No overload matches
> this call.
>
> The last overload gave the following error.
> Argument of type '(req: express.Request, res: Response, next: express.NextFunction) => Promise' is not assignable to parameter
> of type 'RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs,
> Record<string, any>>'.Type '(req: express.Request, res: Response,
> next: express.NextFunction) => Promise' is not assignable to
> type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs,
> Record<string, any>>'.   Types of parameters 'res' and 'res' are
> incompatible.
> Type 'Response<any, Record<string, any>, number>' is missing the following properties from type 'Response': headers, ok,
> redirected, statusText, and 8 more.
>
> 10 router.get('/me', protect, getMe);

Here is middleware:

```
import express from "express";
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../model/userModel');

export const protect = async ( req: express.Request, res: Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {
  const { authorization } = req.headers;
  next();
}
```

Here it is invoked in routers:

```
import express from "express";
const { getMe } = require('../controller/controller');
export const router = express.Router();
import { protect } from '../middleware/authMiddleWare';

router.get('/me', protect, getMe);
```

How to get rid of this error?

Comment: Try `npm add -D @types/express`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the function signature to (you are not retrieving the `Response` type correctly):

```
export const protect = async (
  req: express.Request,
  res: express.Response,
  next: express.NextFunction
) => { ... };
```